# Simple intro to calculus?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Is there a simple, clear introduction to calculus that is readily available (preferably free, but can be paid) and is simple enough for someone merely mediocre at math to grasp?

Ideally, this source would

a) introduce symbols and nomenclature while making them understandable and inspiring confidence in applying them beyond the source,

b) give the consumer the tools they need to solve or at least attempt problems well beyond the source, and

c) not make all of it dumb and boring.

Thanks!

Comment: Early Calc is probably one of the best covered subjects on the internet. Go for a spin on YouTube, you'll find lots. I personally learned a lot from PatrickJMT and KhanAcademy at this stage.

Comment: Although old, I greatly enjoyed the lecture series by Herbert Gross available on youtube as a part of MiT's opencourseware.  [See here for a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLW18-jILJ66t9KZvoPpN6bDQaP7Yg42Hh).  It is mostly lecture with some examples thrown in, but he has a great way of explaining things.  [See also](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-006-calculus-revisited-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/) the ocw.mit.edu page for the course itself where you can find additional resources and exercises.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) which is your best bet and is free in that it has problems you solve after each video or after every few.

And there are [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx) which is also free and the notes start by reviewing what you need from precalculus and are very clear and thorough.

Also there is a video recording of [Calculus course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/index.htm) that was taught MIT on their opencourseware site which is also for free.

I can't think of any other resources other than Youtube that I think would satisfy what your looking for. The best introduction money can get you is to invest in a Calculus Book like [Stewarts Calculus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538497904) which has a [site](http://stewartcalculus.com/) for extra material and exercises I believe. If you read an introductory text like that slowly and carefully I believe it shouldn't be a bad introductory experience at all.

Good luck and I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 1):

Youtube is your best friend. Try Khanacademy, download any book for calculus(or just see its table of contents and try to search the topics on youtube!

Answer (score 1):

Coursera really helped me learn calculus properly way too late.

Ohio state pretty consistent calculus courses. My favorite was the Upenn sequence, although I do not know how often they are offered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend what basically everyone else is saying by using PatrickJMT and Khanacademy. I would personally mix text and videos until you find the right combination that is to your liking as what you could consider as dull/boring could be the most entertaining for someone else. I would also head up to your local library for some calculus books.